# Ubuntu refused to connect wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I work with Ubuntu machine on windows.
I install lighthouse on my ubuntu and when I try to run it fail.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:36107
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 36107
}
```

The same projects run well on my mac os.
How can I fix this issue on ubuntu with WSL?

Thanks.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a local address.  If you type `ip address`, it will list the addresses that your session knows about.

Comment: how can I make it work? @cup

Comment: Can you run `wsl -l -v` from either a cmd or powershell prompt and post the result in your query.  It depends on whether you're running wsl1 or wsl2.

Comment: * Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2

Comment: Sorry - I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and wsl 1.  Maybe someone else with your configuration can help.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cup